# Python random.sample: return whole list instead of "Sample larger than population" error

Tags: python

I want to take a random sample of k elements from a list, using python's random.sample.
The size of the population is not known a-priori, and in some cases it may be less then k: in this case I just want the whole list returned.

It looks to me a pretty common and straightforward use case, so I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this code that I find a bit verbose:

```
# whole_population is a list of elements
# k is an int with  the size of the sample needed
random.sample(whole_population, min(k, len(whole_population))
```

And instead have something like this:

```
random.sample(whole_population, k, error_if_k_too_big=False)
```

Comment: You can see the function docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). TL;DR: no. You could write your own wrapper function with this behaviour, though.

Comment: I don't think that first example looks all that verbose - if you wanted, you could simply do it on two lines, with the first being `sample_size = min(k, len(whole_population))` and the second being `random.sample(whole_population, sample_size)`.

Comment: your code is fine as it is, clearer than any other alternative

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy yes after your answers I think too there are no better solutions. Doing it in 2 lines is effectively more clear

Answer (score 2):

You could add an `if` statement:

```
if k > len(whole_population):
    k = len(whole_population)
```

Meaning `k` will never be greater then the number of elements in `whole_population`, therefore the condition mentioned below will be met.

> and in some cases it may be less then k: in this case I just want the whole list returned.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is that I cannot change the k as I will need to reuse it, so I would need to introduce another variable and so it becomes as verbose as the former one

Comment: @magnum87 ah perhaps using `min(k, len(whole_population)` in the method call is the best idea then

Answer (score 1):

You could use error handling:

```
try:
    return random.sample(whole_population, k)
except ValueError:
    return whole_population
```

Comment: `except ValueError`

Comment: Edited. Good catch, it's always good to be descriptive in case other exceptions might be raised.

Comment: yes exactly- "Good catch" is also a nice pun! I remain unconvinced this is better than the OP solution though

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is:

```py
random.sample(whole_population, min(k, len(whole_population))
```